# How do you migrate a Visual Studio deployment project `deployproj`?

Tags: .net-core, deployment

[image]

- we have a Deployment project that targets .Net framework projects
- we migrated the framework projects to core
- the deployment project won't accept references to dotnet 6.0

is there a way to upgrade deployment project to accept dotnet 6.0 projects?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft does have documentation on this topic [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/installer-projects-net-core?view=vs-2022).

Once you have the extension installed it should allow you to edit the installer project. I had to recreate the outputs according to the instructions. So it's not really a migration. It's a bit like starting over.

I recommend publishing to single file, if you can, and then referencing the publish profile `.pubxml` in the `Publish Items` output.

After following everything I had what appeared, in the GUI, like a good project. It still wouldn't build citing some components had been removed.

I had to additionally:

1. Remove all framework dependencies. (This creates the setup.exe to install dependencies)
2. Remove all custom actions

There might be ways of doing this with the gui but I just ended up editing the setup project file. It's much faster than trying to understand the design language of this plugin.

Remove everything in the section:

```
    "Deployable"
    {
        "CustomAction"
        {
```

You can add any custom actions that you need later. For now, the old ones aren't going to work.